# Python string indexing bug?

Tags: python, string, indexing

I ran into an interesting behavior in Python string indexing and I think might be a bug.

The purpose of my code is to perform a series of manipulation to turn a hex string into binary (12 bits) and take a subset (10 LSB) of the binary string

The code that gives the result I expect looks like this:

```
def test (hex):
    print (bin(int(hex,16))[2:].zfill(12)[3:12])
```

if input "1", i.e. hex = "1"

`bin(int(hex,16))` returns `0b1` as expected

`bin(int(hex,16))[2:]` gets rid of the leading `0b` and returns `1`-- works as expected [2:] give the 3rd char and onwords

`bin(int(hex,16))[2:].zfill(12)` returns `0000_0000_0001` ("_" added for illustration purpose)

now comes the interesting part, in order to get the 10 LSB, i.e. the 3rd to 12th char one would use

`bin(int(hex,16))[2:].zfill(12)[2,11]`

however, it seems I had to use `bin(int(hex,16))[2:].zfill(12)[3,12]` to get `00_0000_0001`, which seems to suggest that somehow the indexing became `1` based instead of `0` based after the `.zfill(12)`?

The results is obtained with Python 3.4.1

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Here is the test code:

```
def test (hex):
    print (int(hex,16)) # bfn hex string to intege
    print (bin(int(hex,16))) # integer to binary string "return 0b...."
    print (bin(int(hex,16))[2:]) # get rid of the leading "0b"
    print (bin(int(hex,16))[2:].zfill(12)) # fill the string to length of 12 bits
    print (bin(int(hex,16))[2:].zfill(12)[3:12])
```

to test:

```
test("1")
```

output:

```
1
0b1
1
000000000001
0000000001
```

Comment: what about the sign bit?

Comment: could you provide examples of your test inputs to reproduce the odd behaviour? I feel like you might be using a number that is 13 bits long already (so zfill(12) does not add nor crop any digit)

Comment: are you suggesting the .zfill() has introduced an additional sign bit (and it is not visible in print())?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> hex = "1"
>>> bin(int(hex, 16))
'0b1'
>>> bin(int(hex, 16))[2:]
'1'
>>> bin(int(hex, 16))[2:].zfill(12)
'000000000001'
>>> bin(int(hex, 16))[2:].zfill(12)[2:]
'0000000001'
>>> bin(int(hex, 16))[2:].zfill(12)[2:11]
'000000000'
```

As you can see, using a slice of `2:11` as an index does not include character number 11 (the 12th character in the string). There is no bug in Python's string indexing.

If you want to index right up the the end of the string the best way to do that is to use an empty index as the second element of the slice, as I did in the second-to-last statement above.

Comment: thanks, but I thought using indexing of 2:11 SHOULD include the 12th character in the string (3rd to 12th), since [2:0] gave the string starting from the 3rd char (hence 0 based)

Comment: Nope. As long as neither `m` nor `n` are greater than `len(s)` then `len(s[m:n])` is always equal to `n - m`. See the [documentation on slicing](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings).

Comment: ah yes you are absolutely correct! still not used to the convention Python provided how a omitted second index is useful! thanks!